# How to filter this list of div elements with the keyup event

Tags: javascript

I want to filter with the keyup event, on the `input` html element: when the user enters something, I want to show just the `div` elements that contain that name 
of "the protein".

The `div` with class "elementsName" is the element which contains those protein names; `.theMainSectionInTheModalBody` is a `div` element.

I know that it is much easier with list elements, but I must use `div`, because positioning my elements (image, text, etc) in just a list element is hard.

`proteins` is just an array of objects, where all elements are inputed.

```
const theLookOfTheProteinsInTheModalBody = () => 
{
  for(let elements of proteins) {
    $('.theMainSectionInTheModalBody').append
    (`
      <div class="calculatorBox">
        <span class="openTheDescriptionText">&#43;</span>
          <div class="elementsName">${ elements.name } <span>${ elements.price }</span></div>
          <span><img class="small" src=${elements.image} /></span>
      </div> 


      <div class="panel">
        <p class="calculatorBoxText">${elements.text}</p>
      </div>
  `)
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <span class="closeTheModalBox">&times;</span>
    <h3>Your current sum from the shopping</h3>
    <input type="text" id="filter" />
    <button class="sortByHighestPrices">Sort the prortein by the highest price</button>
    <button class="sortByLowestPrices">Sort the prortein by the lowest price</button>
    <div id="sum"></div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="theMainSectionInTheModalBody"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you've shared the code that creates your elements. Instead, what we need to see is the HTML for your input, the HTML that it should be filtering, and the JS for the keyup event. Please take a minute to provide that and we can help you figure out what's going wrong!

Comment: It is invalid HTML to add to your `ul` child elements that are not `li` (like `div`).

Comment: i've forgot to change,it works same as with div,previous i had list elements there,i need to fitler with key up throught the divs now

Comment: _"but I must use div, because positioning my elements ... in just a list element is hard"_ — you can style an `li` element in every way you can style a `div` element, so it's not really true that you _must_ use a div... and as trincot says, adding the divs to a `ul` create an invalid document, and once a document is invalid then the effects of CSS and Javascript become less predictable, and can change across browsers (as browsers are free to interpret invalid documents in different ways)

Comment: You cant insert image on right and text on.left in list element because the starting point.of the.elements in li is.fixed,that s why they are list elements.I ve changed to div and works same with js and css as before !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to perform the filtering and sorting on an array, and not directly on the DOM elements. With minor modification, your existing function can be used to re-populate the list based on a filtered/sorted array:

- It should take the array as argument
- It should clear the DOM content before populating

Better use the `input` event than the `keyup` event. Also bind click handlers to your buttons, and let those buttons first sort the original `proteins` array before calling a common `refresh` function. That latter function should then apply the filter and pass the filtered array to the function you have (with above changes):

```js
const theLookOfTheProteinsInTheModalBody = (proteins) => { // pass the argument
  $('.theMainSectionInTheModalBody').empty(); // <-- clear list before populating
  for(let elements of proteins) {
    $('.theMainSectionInTheModalBody').append(`
      <div class="calculatorBox">
          <span class="openTheDescriptionText">&#43;<\/span>
          <div class="elementsName">${ elements.name } <span>${ elements.price }<\/span><\/div>
          <span><img class="small" src="${elements.image}" /><\/span>
      <\/div>
      <div class="panel">
        <p class="calculatorBoxText">${elements.text}<\/p>
      <\/div>
    `);
  }
};

// Sample data
var proteins = [{
    name: "banana",
    price: 12.33,
    image: "test.img",
    text: "they are yellow"
}, {
    name: "apple",
    price: 9.25,
    image: "test.img",
    text: "one apple a day..."
}];

function refresh() {
    const find = $("#filter").val();
    // Only pass filtered list to display function:
    theLookOfTheProteinsInTheModalBody(proteins.filter(elem => elem.name.includes(find)));    
}

// Use input event (not keyup)
$("#filter").on("input", refresh);
$(".sortByHighestPrices").click(() => {
    proteins.sort((a,b) => b.price - a.price);
    refresh();
});
$(".sortByLowestPrices").click(() => {
    proteins.sort((a,b) => a.price - b.price);
    refresh();
});

refresh();
```

```css
.elementsName{ display: inline-block }
.small { width: 20px; height: 20px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-header">
    <span class="closeTheModalBox">&times;</span>
    <h3>Your current sum from the shopping</h3>
    <input type="text" id="filter" />
    <button class="sortByHighestPrices">Sort the prortein by the highest price</button>
    <button class="sortByLowestPrices">Sort the prortein by the lowest price</button>
    <div id="sum"></div>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="theMainSectionInTheModalBody"></div>
</div>
```